# Excel formula doesn't work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have these numbers (5,6,5,7,7,9,4,8,9) in K1:S1. and have this formula

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($K1:$S1,SMALL(IF($K1:$S1=5,COLUMN($K1:$S1)),COLUMN(K:K))),"")}
```

in U1:Z1. This formula is supposed to pick same numbers (in this example 5) and put them in the cells U1:Z1 if there are any. The same formula is used for all available numbers in the list in different cells. but I am having problem with this formula, it doesn't work right now. I can't figure out why. I would be glad if someone can suggest an alternative formula for this function or tell me what is wrong with the formula.

Sample excel file (updated): https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoGkZUHlKui9gRzvwv2CVLi5rOtc

Comment: Did you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when you tried to enter it?

Comment: yes, I did. Still I couldn't run the formula.

Comment: Removing the `IFERROR` returns the `#NUM!` error.  If you use the formula evaluate tool, you will see that your formula is looking for the 11th smallest value in an array of nine values. Hence the error.  *Since you do not show the results you are looking for, I cannot recommend any changes*

Comment: To make the formula work and be more robust replace COLUMN(K:K) with COLUMNS function referring to first cell with formula, you say that’s U1 so in U1 use COLUMNS($U1:U1). That should fix it, but for this specific example there are easier ways to achieve this

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks for your feedback. I updated the excel file. you can see now the expected result there.

Comment: .....e.g. =IF(COUNTIF($K1:$S1,5)>=COLUMNS($U1:U1),5,””)

Comment: @barryhoudini thanks a lot for your suggestion. this is much simpler, and it works. I added iferror in front of it. if you post your solution as an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: OK, I posted as an answer....

Comment: .....and also, for completeness, an alternative to your original formula - that needs change as I suggested above but also additional change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps for simpler suggestion....

`=IF(COUNTIF($K1:$S1,5)>=COLUMNS($U1:U1),5,"")`

You shouldn’t need `IFERROR` with this version

To make your original formula work try this version in U1 copied across

`=IFERROR(INDEX($K1:$S1,SMALL(IF($K1:$S1=5,COLUMN($K1:$S1)-COLUMN($K1)+1),COLUMNS($U1:U1))),"")`